# (InternalError): script too large stack... when requesting 50000+ records in Firefox

Tags: performance, firefox, smartgwt, listgrid

I am using Smart GWT 2.4.

I am displaying a report with around 20 columns which are combination of string, numerics and date types. The report works in Fire Fox when I request less than 50000 records. But when I request more than 50000 records it throws the below error and breaks without showing the report.

(InternalError): script too large stack: vjb([object Object], fileName:.............

The same report works fine in Chrome even for 100,00+ records. I tried in various versions of firefox from 8.0 to 12.0.

Can you please suggest a workaround for solving this issue and be able to display 100,000 records in Firefox. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Vamsi

Comment: @Jean-MichelGarcia :I am also facing the same issue can u plz help me.How can i implement pagination in ListGrid.

Comment: Something like this ? http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=22189&highlight=listgrid+pagination